# MapView not getting displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Application just displays a plain skin colored screen instead of a mapView.

**I have tried followings :**

I have followed all the steps from this [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).
I have enabled `Google Maps Android API v2` in Google API console.
I have generated an API key for android. Also tried creating several times. Even on different machine.
I have added `Google play services` to my project. 
I tried setting `Custom debug keystore` to `Default debug keystore`. 
My AVD target is set to Google APIs level 17.

**Manifest.xml file :**

```
<permission
    android:name="com.objectlounge.ridesharebuddy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.objectlounge.ridesharebuddy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY"/>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

My activity and layout files are same as in this [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map).

I use *emulator.* I am not sure if android mapView v2 is supported in emulator.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Google maps V2 doesn't work on emulator! You should use a real device only.

Comment: @Flavio Yes, you are right. I come to know the same from other source.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity extends a `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

And replace you xml layout fragment with the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: No, I don't need to use `FragmentActivity`. Google docs itself uses `Activity`. Just look at the end of the page whose link I have provided in question.

Comment: @Akash, What's the result of your implementation in a real device?